# AngularJS "$resource:badcfg" Error

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm encountering a very odd error, although I presume it's probably easy to fix, I can't seem to find the solution, not in the angular docs or on stackoverflow :S

Code Summary: An ajax request is sent to server, using ng-resource to retrieve data that is formatted as JSON. It works fine when there is a single JSON object, however when I have multiple JSON objects for example:

```
        {
            "letters": [
                {}
            ],
            "words": [
                {}
            ]
        }
```

It throws the badcfg error.

I don't understand why and how to solve it.

```
        app.factory('getWords', ['$resource',
      function ($resource, $cacheFactory) {
        return {
            all: $resource('/lane/api/getWords/:letter', {
                letter: '@letter'
            }, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: $cacheFactory
                },
                'query': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: false,
                    fomrat: 'JSON'
                }
            })
          }]);
```

The code I am using to trigger that service and access that data is this:

```
       $scope.words = getWords.all.query({letter: $scope.letter});
       console.log($scope.words);console.log($scope.words.words);
```

I hope I'm being clear, thanks

Comment: Did you install ngResource?

Comment: yeah, like I said it works fine for single JSON objects--so  ngResource is working fine--the problem is with multiple JSON objects..BTW, i tried with 'isArray: true' as well that doesn't seem to help

Comment: Poease, post the whole error message when asking to debug an error. Alsopost the exact format of the JSON data in both cases.

Comment: Sorry, this is the exact error link in the debugging console: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is going through this apparent conundrum, fear not the solution is simple, lol after greying a few hairs, It looks like all you have to do is make sure that isArray is set to false (in my case, I set it to false on the Query method).

Then when you are calling up that service make sure you use a (callback?) function that grabs the returned data and allows you to access the objects within it.

Perhaps a more seasoned programmer can explain what I am trying to explain better than me :)

Here is the working:

```
app.factory('getWords', ['$resource', function($resource, $cacheFactory){

        return {

    all: $resource('/lane/api/getWords/:letter', {letter: '@letter'}, {
        'get': { method:'GET', cache: $cacheFactory },
        'query': { method:'GET', cache: $cacheFactory, isArray:false}
        }),
      find: $resource('/lane/api/getWords/:word', {word: '@word'}, {
        'get': { method:'GET', cache: $cacheFactory },
        'query': { method:'GET', cache: $cacheFactory, isArray:true }
        })
      }

}]);
```

and when you'd like to access the data through this service(getWords)

```
  getWords.all.query({letter: $scope.letter}, function (data) {
  $scope.words = data.words;
  });
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: The standard practice is to use `Resource.get` for objects and `Resource.query` for arrays. Breaking that convention creates code that is confusing for other programmers to understand and maintain.